# Is there a better and cleaner method other than getInitialProps

Tags: next.js

I have a nextJS site that has a custom _app.js file with the following code.

I have dynamic content from a cms that i use getServerSide props from for each of the pages I have.

```
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const { global } = pageProps
  if (global == null) {
    return <ErrorPage statusCode={404} />
  }


  if(global.attributes === undefined){
    return <Component />
  }

  const { metadata, favicon, metaTitleSuffix } = global.attributes


  return (
    <>
      {/* Favicon */}
      <Head>
        <link
          rel="shortcut icon"
          href={getStrapiMedia(favicon.data.attributes.url)}
        />
        
      </Head>
      {/* Global site metadata */}
      <DefaultSeo
        titleTemplate={`%s | ${metaTitleSuffix}`}
        title="Page"
        description={metadata.metaDescription}
      />
      {/* Display the content */}
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext)
  const globalLocale = await getGlobalData(appContext.router.locale)

  return {
    ...appProps,
    pageProps: {
      global: globalLocale,
    },
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

Two questions in a way.

A. Do I even need this getInitialProps?
B. Is there a better way of using getInitialProps

Let me know if anymore code is needed

Comment: You want to try to use getStaticProps, which gives you rendering options on each page. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props. Otherwise your implementation looks good.

Comment: @serraosays The problem is that you cant use getStaticProps in the _app.js, unless they have changed this feature?

Comment: I didn't realize this was `_app.js` - you should do your data fetches in components or in your `/pages` folder. Can you refactor this over to one of those?